# Problem with table of contents. Chapters appeared different from sections

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the following code. My problem is that the table of contents displays the page number of chapters without `\hfill`, next to the title, unlike to the section titles which appears with dot filling in space (between numbers and titles) and aligned with the others page numbers of sections.

EDIT: Here is the complete code which i run.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,leqno]{book}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}% adds dot after chapter title in ToC
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\hfill}} % for chapters
%\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
 \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
 \usepackage[space]{grffile} % For spaces in paths
 \usepackage{etoolbox} % For spaces in paths
 \makeatletter % For spaces in paths


 \patchcmd\Gread@eps{\@inputcheck#1 }{\@inputcheck"#1"\relax}{}{}
 \makeatother
\def\quotient#1#2{
    \raise0.5ex\hbox{$#1$}\small/\lower1ex\hbox{$#2$}}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Use custom style %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{ptixiaki}
\author{Author Name}
\title{Title of thesis}
\subtitle{\textlatin{}}
\projectlevel{Thesis}
\date{4 january 2016}
\advisor{Advisor Name}
\committeememberone{Prof. 1}
\committeemembertwo{Prof. 2}
%% leave empty if less than 3: \committeemembertwo{}
\committeememberthree{Prof 3}
\dedication{dedication}
\university{University}
\department{department}
\separator{,\ }
%% another separator
%% \separator{\ $|$\ }
%% yet another one
%% \separator{\ \ding{'107}\ }
%% a simpler separator 
%% \separator{\ $\cdot$\ }
\city{Name of City}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%% New theorems %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]         
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Λήμμα}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Πρόταση}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Πόρισμα}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Ορισμός}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Παρατήρηση}
\newtheorem{example}{Παράδειγμα}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Document starts %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Start Roman numbering %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{roman}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makecover

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table of contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

Text.

\cleardoublepage


%%%%%%%%%%% Return to normal numbering %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Σελίδα}\par}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Chapter Title} 

\end{document}
```

[image: ...and a picture]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice minimal example. However, I don't get the output as you: I get leader dots as expected. Are you using the `book` class or another one? The `\makecover` command looks suspicious.

Comment: [I get everything as expected](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ilB.png), is that what you get with the code provided?

Comment: At me doesn't work (well, after recent MikTeX upgrade I experienced a lot of problems, many packages doesn't work anymore). However, after remove all unnecessary packages the `\tableofcontents` show contents with dotted leaders (as expected).

Comment: @egreg I'm using only book class. \makecover was useful to create the cover for my book. Also, the code which was creating the cover removed from me before post my problem here. 
Now, if i compile the code after remove some packages (from cover code) i'm getting the right result in my screen. I'll search for the problem more extensively.  
Thank you all for your replies!

Comment: @mpouxa Then the issue could be your cover. Would you post it?

Comment: @alenanno Sure! I edit the post and added the complete code.

Comment: @mpouxa Where can we download the `ptixiaki` package?

Comment: @alenanno Here : http://www.filedropper.com/ptyxiaki

Comment: Is there any news here?